# hyperlink selected text in wpf RichTextBox & set selection from code

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink, richtextbox

How can I add a hyperlink to a selection in a wpf RichTextBox?

For example, if my RichTextBox says:

"Send me to Stack Overflow."

and I highlight "Overflow", then click a button to make a hyperlink out of it to go to "www.stackoverflow.com" How can I achieve this?

Also, I'm trying to highlight text from code, and I can't figure out how. To highlight the whole RichTextBox I have tried this, but it hasn't worked:

```
    TextPointer myTextPointer1 = rtb.Document.ContentStart;
    TextPointer myTextPointer2 = rtb.Document.ContentEnd;

    rtb.Selection.Select(myTextPointer1, myTextPointer2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    TextSelection ts = rtb.Selection;
    TextPointer start = ts.Start;
    TextPointer end = ts.End;

    TextRange before = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, start);
    TextRange after = new TextRange(end, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
    TextRange linker = new TextRange(start, end);

    Paragraph myParagraph = new Paragraph();
    myParagraph.Inlines.Clear();
    myParagraph.Inlines.Add(before.Text);

    Hyperlink hyperLink = new Hyperlink();
    hyperLink.Inlines.Add(ts.Text);

    hyperLink.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(hyperLink_Click);
    myParagraph.Inlines.Add(hyperLink);
    myParagraph.Inlines.Add(after.Text);

    rtb.Document.Blocks.Clear();

    rtb.Document.Blocks.Add(myParagraph);
```